# How do I call a function on the sepoila network using web3.py?

Tags: remix, blockchain, web3.py

I've been trying to call a function on my solidity smart contract but keep getting

TypeError: Transaction must include these fields: {'nonce'}

Here is the solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

// import the web3.storage interface
//import "contracts/1_Storage.sol";

// define a contract that implements the web3.storage interface
contract IPFSStorage{
    // define a mapping to store the IPFS hashes
    mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public hashes;

    // function to add a new IPFS hash to the mapping
    function addHash(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) public {
        // set the value at the given key in the mapping
        hashes[key] = value;
    }

    // function to retrieve an IPFS hash from the mapping
    function getHash(bytes32 key) public view returns (bytes32) {
        // return the value at the given key in the mapping
        return hashes[key];
    }
}
```

And here is the python file:

```
# import the web3 library
import web3
import json

# define the contract address
contract_address = "0x22F7ef1fDecA9a989258D6e3A87e0ebd3f1f801A"

# connect to the Ethereum network
w3 = web3.Web3(web3.Web3.HTTPProvider("https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/0776cf37dfb04efdacd478388c7c1dec"))

# load the contract ABI
with open("abi.json") as file:
    abi = json.load(file)

# create a contract instance
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

# define the wallet credentials
private_key = "..."
wallet_address = "..."

# unlock the wallet
w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key)

# function to add a new IPFS hash to the contract
def add_hash(key, value):
    # build the transaction
    tx = contract.functions.addHash(key, value).buildTransaction({
        "from": wallet_address,
        "gas": 1000000,
        "gasPrice": w3.toWei("10", "gwei"),
    })

    # sign the transaction
    signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key=private_key)

    # send the transaction
    tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed)
    # wait for the transaction to be mined
    receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

    # check the transaction status
    if receipt["status"] == 1:
        print("Hash added successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to add hash.")

# function to retrieve an IPFS hash from the contract
def get_hash(key):
    # call the getHash function
    result = contract.functions.getHash(key).call()

    # return the result
    return result

# add a new IPFS hash to the contract
add_hash("0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")

# retrieve an IPFS hash from the contract
value = get_hash("0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I did not enter the nonce part

```
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_address)
```

And later on:

```
# function to add a new IPFS hash to the contract
def add_hash(key, value):
    # build the transaction
    tx = contract.functions.addHash(key, value).buildTransaction({
        "from": wallet_address,
        "gas": 1000000,
        "gasPrice": w3.toWei("10", "gwei"),
        "nonce": nonce,
    })
```